# Brackets.io in built support for TypeScript

Tags: typescript, intellisense, adobe-brackets

Does brackets.io have in-built support for typescript?  I tried the plugin from below link

https://github.com/fdecampredon/brackets-typescript

Steps
1) OS Windows 8.1
2) Installed latest version of Brackets
3) Installed Brackets-TypeScript
4) created .brackets.json and added

```
{
    "typescript": {
        "target": "ES5",
        "module": "AMD",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "sources" : [
            "src/declarations//*.ts",
            "src/main//*.ts"
        ]
    }
}
```

5) Still now luck for code completion of Intellisense.
I have created issue in the same Github, but it looks inactive for sometime now.https://github.com/fdecampredon/brackets-typescript/issues/34

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out after I posted this request in [Github](https://github.com/fdecampredon/brackets-typescript/issues/34) page of the plugin.

there is one other typescript [plugin](https://github.com/tomsdev/brackets-typescript-code-intel) for brackets and if you have installed it, that intervenes with this.

right one is [fdecampredon/brackets-typescript](https://github.com/fdecampredon/brackets-typescript)

Answer (score 3):

> Does brackets.io have in-built support for typescript? I tried the plugin from below link

No.

The plugin you are pointing to is the de facto one.

Comment: Thanks, I am trying to setup dev environment for Node JS and stuck into this.

Answer (score 1):

Please use https://github.com/zaggino/brackets-typescript if you need a TypeScript plugin. I'm using this one and it is perfect :)